# Camera permission are been ignore in Kotlin app

Tags: android, kotlin

I as developing an app which make use of a camera future using cameraX plugin and Kotlin lenguage.

My problem come with the camera permision which is returning '-1' when call:

```
requestPermissions(arrayOf("android.permission.Camera"), 10)
```

My manifest file is this:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
    android:required="true"
    android:requiredFeature="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"
    android:required="true" />
```

And regading the code of my activity to manage this permision is this:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, "android.permission.Camera") == -1) {
                requestPermissions(arrayOf("android.permission.Camera"), 10)
            } else {
                imageCapture?.takePicture(
                    ActivityCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
                    object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
                        @OptIn(ExperimentalGetImage::class)
                        override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
                            useCase.setResult(
                                ApiCameraResponse(
                                    result = ApiCameraResponse.Result(
                                        imageContent = Convert.imageProxyToByteArray(image = image),
                                        imageType = "png"
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        }

                        override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                            logger.error("Error taking picture: $exception")
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
```

This function is call by a button which is suppose to open the camera, but is not. So hiw can be possible although th permission s confure staticly and dinamicly, but doesn't work.

Take thanks in advance!

[EDIT]

After some test, I'm still getting "Permission not been granted", due to I get a "-1" value in onRequestPermissionResult method, but I realize that when open the manifest file, and check the mergued manifest I get this:

[image]

So is something wrong with the permission of my app at manifest file, but I already try to set the property required to true, and doesn't change.

Here are my current camera permission of manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
        android:required="true"
        android:requiredFeature="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Any clue??

Comment: "android.permission.Camera" AND "android.permission.CAMERA".

Comment: I've already checked, it's not case sensitive

Comment: Are you telling that checkSelfPermission continues to return -1? Unclear where you get that -1.

Comment: `Take thanks in advance!` Sorry i do not take that bad habit. We expect you to express thanks only after been helped to satisfaction.

Comment: Thanks ! But yes you I've already checked you suggestion

Comment: But **why** are you using those hardcoded values instead of the existing constants `Manifest.permission.CAMERA` and `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED`? Also, where is your implementation of `onRequestPermissionsResult`? Keep in mind that you can't trigger an infinite number of permission request dialogs. If the user has denied a permission a certain number of times, Android will not show any permission dialog when you call `requestPermissions` again.

Comment: I hardcode the permission due to constants appears to doesn't works. I 've implemented on onRequestPermissionsResult, but the result comes in '-1' due to permission are not been ask to the user. that's the bug. The application is not asking the user the required permissions

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong permission constant. The `android.permission.Camera permission` constant is deprecated and should not be used. Instead, you should use the `Manifest.permission.CAMERA permission` constant.
The correct code should be:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == -1) {
    requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), 10)
} else {
    imageCapture?.takePicture(
        ActivityCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
        object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
            @OptIn(ExperimentalGetImage::class)
            override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
                useCase.setResult(
                    ApiCameraResponse(
                        result = ApiCameraResponse.Result(
                            imageContent = Convert.imageProxyToByteArray(image = image),
                            imageType = "png"
                        )
                    )
                )
            }

            override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                logger.error("Error taking picture: $exception")
            }
        }
    )
}
```

In addition to using the correct permission constant, you should also make sure that you are requesting the permission in the `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method if the permission is not granted. For example :

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions : Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

    if (requestCode == 10) {
        if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission granted, take the picture
            imageCapture?.takePicture(
                ActivityCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
                object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
                    @OptIn(ExperimentalGetImage::class)
                    override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
                        useCase.setResult(
                            ApiCameraResponse(
                                result = ApiCameraResponse.Result(
                                    imageContent = Convert.imageProxyToByteArray(image = image),
                                    imageType = "png"
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    }

                    override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                        logger.error("Error taking picture: $exception")
                    }
                }
            )
        } else {
            // Permission denied, handle the error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such completed answer. I check that the problem is when the method onRequestPermissionsResult is called, the array grantResults, and permissions, are empty, but I the requestCode is correct. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way to ask for camera permission .

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (checkPermission()) {
        //if permission grante

        } else {
            requestPermission();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission is not granted
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void requestPermission() {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // execute logic if permission granted 
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access permissions",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                requestPermission();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
}
```